# BigQuery auto fill doesn't work when pasting code in to web UI

Tags: autocomplete, google-bigquery, autofill

Sometimes when I paste SQL into BigQuery web UI, I can't use the table alias, full stop & tab to show what fields I can pick from.

Generally it works if I type the query from scratch.

Just wondering if anyone has noticed this and what workarounds there are around this?

Comment: Can you post an example query which does not work for you when you copy and paste it to the BigQuery UI ? Also, do you get any error when running this query?  In my experience, every time I copied and pasted a query I hit _ctrl+enter_ and the query runs without any error.

Comment: Hey u don't have an actual query but it happens for any query. The query itself runs fine. They are working queries. So all in doing is trying to bring in another field in the SELECT query and it doesn't auto fill after I use the <table alias>.